# How to add an additional column in a database table in Sqlite?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, alter-table

I have a SQLite table for students.

I want to add another column in students for student gender. I have below code to create my table.

How can I additional column "Gender" in my student's table?

```
private static final String TAG = "SyncStudents";

//Declare tables and fields where we will store all the amdins information.
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "studetns";
private static final String COL1 = "id";
private static final String COL2 = "firstname";
private static final String COL3 = "lastname";
private static final String COL4 = "age";
private static final String COL5 = "dob";
private static final String COL6 = "cir";
private static final String COL7 = "class";
private static final String COL8 = "address";
private static final String COL9 = "grade";


public SyncRoutesHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    //Create the table
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + COL2 + " TEXT," + COL3 + " TEXT," + COL4 + " INTEGER," +
            COL5 + " INTEGER," + COL6 + " INTEGER," + COL7 + " TEXT," + COL8 + " TEXT," + COL9 + " INTEGER )";

    //Execute the above statement
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE students ADD COLUMN genger TEXT DEFAULT NULL");

}
```

I tried to write below the line in "OnUpdate" method but it does not work.

```
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE students ADD COLUMN gender TEXT DEFAULT NULL");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **onUpgrade** to run you have to increase the version number which is the 4th paramter of the super call. So you need to change

```
super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
```

to

```
super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 2);
```

**However**, as your **onUpgrade** method drops the table and calls **onCreate** you might as well just change the code in the **onCreate** method to include the new column. **This will delete all existing data.**

If you need to retain the existing data then the **onUpgrade** method should just have the single line to ALTER the table and be :-

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE students ADD COLUMN gender TEXT DEFAULT NULL");
}
```

- Note that you should also change the code in the **onCreate** method to include the new column so that a new install will include the new column.

You may wish to have a look at [How To: Android SQLite onUpgrade()](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/how-android-sqlite-onupgrade) as this goes into using the **i** and **i1** values as you would get issues if you then introduced more schema changes and increased the version to 3 (and so on).